# Cannot install bower on Mac

Tags: npm, bower

I was trying to install bower npm on Mac using command `sudo npm install -g bower` and it ask for root password. By leaving password blank and press enter, it showed wrong password. I remember I never change user root password before. 
Low npm install log

[image: npm install log]

Please kindly help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `password` or `root` as they might be the default passwords set.